# How do I change the radio button icon in extjs?

Tags: css, extjs

I have two Ext.menu.CheckItem's in a group. How would I change the checked item's disc icon to something else? I would like to retain the radio button functionality (only one selected), but have a check mark instead of the disc.

```
var options = new Ext.Button({
    allowDepress: false,
    menu: [
        {checked:true,group:'labels',text:'Option 1'},
        {checked:false,group:'labels',text:'Option 2'}
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that effect (radio controls that look like check boxes) by setting the `inputType` configuration option to `'checkbox'`:

```
var options = new Ext.Button({
    allowDepress: false,
    menu: [
        {inputType:'checkbox',checked:true,group:'labels',text:'Option 1'},
        {inputType:'checkbox',checked:false,group:'labels',text:'Option 2'}
    ]
});
```

As an example, here are two screenshots that show the effect of `inputType:'checkbox'`:

[First screenshot http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2f662f202c.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?2f662f202c.png)

[Second screenshot with the "Red" option  http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/66c002aad2.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?66c002aad2.png)

I modified Ext JS' [Checkbox/Radio Groups demo](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/check-radio.html) and only added the option to the "Red" radio component configuration.